# require js not working with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I am using require js in mvc4 .

**View**

```
<script data-main="/scripts/about" src="/scripts/require.js" ></script>
<article>
<p>
    Use this area to provide additional information.
</p>
</article>
```

**about.js**

```
   require.config({

    paths: {
        page1: '/Scripts/page1',
        page2: '/Scripts/page2',
        knockout : '/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0'
      }

    });

     require(['page1', 'page2','knockout'], function (page1, page2) {

     var car = new page1.Car();
      car.speed(60);

      var cycle = new page2.Cycle();
      cycle.speed(20);



      console.log(car.speed());
     console.log(cycle.speed());
  });
```

**page1.js**

```
    define(function(){

    function Car() {

    var self = this;
    self.speed = ko.observable();

     }

     });
```

**page2**

```
  define(function () {

  function Cycle() {

    var self = this;
    self.speed = ko.observable();

   }

   });
```

In console it says `Car` is undefined.

**Update**

```
  define(['knockout'],function(ko){

   function Car() {

    var self = this;
    self.speed = ko.observable();
    return {
        speed: self.speed() // But don't forget to declare it in the returned object!
       };
     }

  });
```

I did this in both page1 and page2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK requirejs isolates loaded libraries to single file. In your page1 and page2 there is no knockout loaded therefore `ko` namespace is not defined so `ko.observables` are not defined and when you create new Car it will be undefined. To fix this you should load knockout in page1 and page2 also providing `ko` namespace as function argument:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko){

  function Car() {

    var self = this;
    self.speed = ko.observable();

  }

});
```

or using `ko = require('knockout');` or loading a shim for knockout to be a global namespace

**EDIT:**

At least you tried. So here is follow up.

When you do define, there is this function you provide with all your view model and other. It is requirejs function and this function should return something (i.e. your viewModel). This way you can have private and public variables and functions inside defined module.

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko){

  var Car = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.speed = ko.observable();
  }

  return Car;
});
```

The name matters only for this module scope. In your about.js when you import your module you can decide how it will be called:

```
//load page1 script and give returned object 
//(this case a constructor) name: createCar
require(['page1'], function (createCar) {

  // now create new instance of your Car function:
  var car = new createCar();
  car.speed(60);

  console.log(car.speed());
});
```

Comment: also your modules should return something, read about defining modules: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule

Comment: see my update , i tried by returning but still it doesn't work

Comment: It is require define which should return your function. You are defining module that sill doesn't provide anything when called by your about.js. See my edit, I hope this will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your modules need to `return` the code that they represent. For example, your `Car` module should look like this:

```
define(function(){    
    function Car() {
        var self = this;
        self.speed = ko.observable();
    };    
    return Car;
 });
```

The module has to represent something when it is done, either a function (to construct objects), or an object (to represent a singleton). Once your module is defined, you `require` it in another module to use it.

```
define(['pathtoCar/relativeToDataMainAttribute/fromRequireScriptTag'], 
function(Car){
    var ferrari = new Car();
    ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 define(function () {

      function Cycle() {

        var self = this;
        self.speed = ko.observable();

       }

    ///////////////////ADDD   THISSSS NEWWWW LINEEEE//////////

    return new cycle();

   });
```